# How do I come up with a LoT when using longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable

<sup>**Note from Paulo:** I translated the question from Portuguese to English and did some retagging. Some rewording was done, but the general idea (and code) remains the same. You can still find the original question in the edit history.</sup>

---

When using the `longtable` environment to create a table, my list of tables (LoT) does not recognize it, it just recognizes `table`.

```
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables*
\cleardoublepage
```

This is my list:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{1.8cm}|p{5cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{5cm}|}
\caption[]{Lista de requisitos}\label{tabrequisitos}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Requisitos Funcionais}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Requisitos Não-Funcionais}}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Código} & \textbf{Descrição} & \textbf{Código} & \textbf{Descrição} \\
\endfirsthead

\caption{Lista de requisitos (continuação)}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Requisitos Funcionais}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Requisitos Não-Funcionais}}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Código} & \textbf{Descrição} & \textbf{Código} & \textbf{Descrição} \\
\endhead

\hline
\endlastfoot

\hline
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize{}continua na próxima página}
\endfoot

\hline
RF001 & O sistema deve permitir que o aluno, responsável e motorista realizem seu cadastro geral. & RNF001 & O sistema deverá ser desenvolvido para Web e Android.
\\
\hline
RF002 &
O sistema deve permitir que o Aluno, responsável e motorista realizem login na aplicação. &
RNF002 &
O sistema deverá utilizar criptografia para cifrar e decifrar as senhas cadastradas.
\\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: without an example it is impossible to say what is wrong but list of tables lists `\caption` that may be in `table` or in `longtable` (please post in English on this site)

Comment: adicionei um techo do meu código da minha tabela

Comment: @SJSantos Poucas pessoas nesse site ententem português, então se você traduzir sua pergunta para o inglês, mais pessoas vão conseguir entender e te ajudar

Comment: With `\caption[]{Lista de requisitos}` you're explicitly requesting that the `longtable` is not listed in the list of tables. Remove the `[]`.

Comment: What @egreg said. Or add the name of the table, as you want it to appear in the lot into the `[]`. Which is more or less, what this optional parameter is for.

Comment: Muito obrigada, ao retirar o [ ] a as tabelas apareceram na lista.